# A Menu hangs on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, ide, contextmenu

[image]

while using Android Studio to develop an Android app , suddenly this menu appears while right clicking on layout design surface and still appearing although I minimized Android Studio window and refuse to go off until I close the Android studio program

[image]

a way to reproduce this behavior :
1 - open color resource file 
2- right click on a color tag it gives u the following :
 [image]
3- click cancel button and it will again give the following:
[image]
4- clicking cancel again it gives u the following :
[image]

Comment: You can again make this menu?!

Comment: i have edited the question with a way to reproduce this behavior

Comment: OK, I get this error, but when I clicked in bottom toolbar of Windows, it disappeared

Comment: it is just happens when right clicking on the word inside a tag , Like <color> ... <string> ...

Comment: Yes, but you can make it disappeared

Comment: is this a problem with IDE

Comment: I think yes, it is bug. Because the menu which is opened has not clickable items.

Comment: You can check my answer as correct, if you think it is correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is bug. Because the menu which is opened has not clickable items.

Comment: do u suggest any fix ??

Comment: When you click out of AS, the menu will disappear. You can report it as bug to AS.@Sh.Raai

Comment: From Damascus?@Sh.Raai

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211409/discussion-between-sh-raai-and-mohammadmoeingolchin).

Answer (score 1):

This look like a bug ,try reporting about this bug to google . This may work for you.